# Text going under image within a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I'm trying to float three images in one Div. The first one is positioned in the upper left and it doesn't seem to cause any problems, but I simply cant manage to get the text to wrap around the second image (which is supposed to go in the middle right) The div in question is the "TB2" div. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out. https://jsfiddle.net/so9n5r4b/

Here is my HTML:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("Vlootbackground.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -120px;
  right: 71px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 17px;
}
#Banner {
  background-image: url("Vlootheader.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 800px;
  height: 269px;
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 350px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.UH2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#TB2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -18px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  top: -24px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}
.GSimage1 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.GSimage2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 490px;
  margin-bottom: -490px;
}
.GT1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.GT2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GSstyle.css">
  <title>De vloot</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Banner">
    <h1>Geschiedenis</h1>
    <p class="UH2">Uit de tijd dat Marco zijn Polo aan had</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Start</li>
      <li>Geschiedenis</li>
      <li>Kruisers</li>
      <li>Vliegdekschepen</li>
      <li>Onderzeeërs</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="TB2">
    <h2>Er is niet veel veranderd.</h2>
    <img src="GSimage1.jpg" alt="Geschiedenis image 1" class="GSimage1">
    <img src="GSimage2.jpg" alt="Geschiedenis image 2" class="GSimage2">
    <p class="GT1">text</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when you post a question like this its best to make a fiddle @http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it and actually see the problem, chances are people will answer faster if you do so.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/so9n5r4b/ I hope that works, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what your question is asking. I have updated your fiddle to float the image to the right with the text wrapping around it. Let me know if this is what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/so9n5r4b/3/

```
.GSimage2{
  float: right;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    padding-right:40px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

I would also recommend adding each paragraph you have in it's own `<p>...</p>` as I have done in this fiddle.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks a ton, I have used your suggestion for the paragraphs.

Comment: Great, glad to help!